# Appium exception "Can't stop process; it's not currently running"

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

Environment:

- java-client(6.0.0-BETA4)
- server Appium (1.5.0)
- java 1.8

During automated test Appium keeps stalling on me, when running on android emulators.

Few tests just fail due to problem with seems to be server issue:

**Exception:**

> "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error
>   occurred while processing the command. Original error: Can't stop
>   process; it's not currently running"

Is there any known way to avoid this issue?

Here is more stack-trace from Appium server:

```
[debug] [ADB] Running ‘…/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop com.go.android'[debug] [ADB] Pressing the HOME button
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...[debug] [ADB] Pressing the HOME button
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"shutdown"}[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"OK, shutting down"}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Closed client connection
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] Time: 52.015
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] OK (1 test)
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
[error] [UiAutomator] UiAutomator exited unexpectedly with code 0, signal null
[debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'
[debug] [UiAutomator] Shutting down UiAutomator
[debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopping'
[error] [Appium] Had trouble ending session fc510427-6374-4d94-83b4-f008e05f8d69: Can't stop process; it's not currently running (cmd: ‘/…/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb')
[error] [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Can't stop process; it's not currently running (cmd: '/Users/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb')
```

Looks like it fails when exiting app with 'HOME' button.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Why this issue occurs. And how to avoid it. This behaviour is not reproducible every time, but just occasionally. My question is how to avoid this.

Comment: Update the main question with this information for proper analysis

Comment: Can you add more details about teardown function and share the stacktrace? Are you running the 2 devices in parallel?

Comment: Teardown function is overriden method afterInvocation() and stacktrace is above. But think I've located issue, it was a bug in server when OverrideSession param is set on. Still testing to see if this will re-appear, but if it doesn't 100% that this would be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue happened when running tests with 'Allow session override'. 
Turned off this option, and tests didn't fail anymore (ran over 500+) tests, so my conclusion is that this option caused this issue.